# Restore Only few store procedure from mysqldump

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a dump sizing 14GB, I want to extract some procedures from the whole dump (structure and data). Is there any option in MYSQL. I'm using MYSQL 5.1 in windows 7.

```
 Mysql -u root -p "option here " < mydump.sql
```

Comment: I am looking for the same. I think the options available at the time of backup is not available at the time of restore.

Answer (score -1):

just copy the parts you whant to recreate from the dump to a new file using notepad++ or similar programs and run the new scrit against the server

dump just procedures:

```
mysqldump <other mysqldump options> --routines outputfile.sql
```

dump store procedures and triggers

```
mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt <database> > outputfile.sql
```

Comment: do u think 14GB data will open in notepad??

Comment: dump options updateed the answer you can also dump individual tables read the references for mysql

Comment: I have downvoted the answer because it asked to restore only procedures from dump. Dump can contain everything. Answer should be with details : option available at he time of database restore like available database backup.